# React Native thinks image is a module

Tags: ios, image, react-native

This may seem like a duplicate but I've followed the answers to maybe a dozen similar questions on Stack and none of the solutions are working for me.

The React Native [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) say load to local images like so:

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

I've placed the image `3D-home2@x.jpg` in the same folder as the JS file:

[image]

I also tried placing it at the project root:

[image]

I also tried placing it in `Images.xcassets` and loading it like `require('image!3D-home')`.

In between these efforts, I cleared the module cache several times with `yarn start -- --reset-cache`. Did a full XCode project 'clean' several times and rebuilt the app. No matter what I do I get some variation of this error (project name redacted):

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like I'm following the instructions exactly but I cannot get an image to load.

```
<Image
    style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: 10
    }}
    source={ require('./3D-home@2x.jpg') }
/>
```

Comment: This may be dumb, but - what happens if you try to use a `png` image?

Comment: A `png` worked... Wow. React Native doesn't like `jpg`?

Comment: Did another test and apparently it has something to do with the `@2x` in the title. When I removed that from the file name I was able to load a `jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove `@2x` from the file name. This is because React Native offers the ability to automatically swap out images using suffixes, so I was unwittingly trying to do that incorrectly or something:

> You can also use the @2x and @3x suffixes to provide images for
>   different screen densities.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html